# Railscasts, where 'token' variable comes from

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

The open source project [railscasts](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts) has User model ([link to the full file](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/blob/master/app/models/user.rb))

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ........

  def generate_token
    if token.blank? # where's definition of this variable?
      characters = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('1'..'9').to_a
      begin
        self.token = Array.new(32) { characters.sample }.join
      end while self.class.exists?(:token => token)
    end
  end
end
```

Please explain me where the variable `token` came from? Where's the definition of this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referring to the token column for the users table that the User model is wrapping. It is defined by ActiveRecord automatically when abstracting the table schema.

Comment: token and self.token are they referring to the same variable?

Comment: These are both referring to the token column, yes. I can't explain why self is needed :)

Comment: That's why I was confused. Just checked this thing in rails console, you're right